# Is the relaxed solution of an ILP always greater than the solution of an LP?

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I have an LPI maximization problem. Suppose that the objective function is monotonous strictly growing.
With such an assumption, can I deduce that the LP solution is always greater than the LPI solution?
If not, why?
And if yes, why?

Comment: Depends if you are maximizing or minimizing.

Comment: Yeah sorry, I am maximizing it of course. I will change my post

Comment: For any objective, a relaxation will be >= than the optimal integer solution. As the relaxed solution can be identical to the optimal integer solution, I don't think you can tighten this to >. If that is the question.